# Allow access to private S3 bucket only when a particular header is present in request

Tags: amazon-s3, private, policy

I have a private bucket in S3 and would like to only allow access only to requests that include a particular (secret) header, sent from a CDN (not CloudFront, as that would of course be simple to allow using its own id).

So that means writing a bucket policy to allow just those secret-header requests.

I've been doing some research (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) and I can see that you can test other attributes of the request like *aws:Referer* to do a comparison on the referer, and *aws:SourceIp* to do a comparison on the source IP - but how would I go about doing a comparison on a custom header e.g. "*X-my-secret-header*"?

Do bucket policies support testing header values? If so, how?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to specifically do this, and header-based restrictions are of course only genuinely effective against the most naive user, since they are easily forged... but there's support for `User-Agent:` testing.  Does your CDN set a specific user agent header? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#AvailableKeys

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks - I thought as much. Indeed you are quite right - it's a pretty basic defence! No user-agent sadly, so can't do it that way either. Ah well.

Answer (score 6):

AWS recommends using the "Referer" header to store a token and then use an AWS Bucket Policy that restricts requests to `aws:Referer` headers that match the token.  Note that the token is not the actual referer URL, it's just whatever secret you want to use.

You will need to make sure that the requests from your CDN to S3 are over HTTPS so that secret token is encrypted.

This is described in the AWS article [How do I use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/) under the section "Using a website endpoint as the origin, with access restricted by a Referer header"  Assuming you can set the "Referer" header from your CDN to the origin, the same concepts should apply.